# How to check when browser’s window is triggered for load/reload/backward/forward and close in jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I need to take some decisions when browser’s window behave like follows

1.on load

2.on reload

3.on backward and forward

4.on close

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[$.unload](https://api.jquery.com/unload/)

You can use it as

```
$(window).unload(function(){
    //in the case of refresh and if a user clicks a link on the page

});
```

[$.load](https://api.jquery.com/load-event)

```
$(window).load(function(){
    //after the window is fully loaded, including images

});
```

Comment: better to use the `beforeunload` event.